# Set default expire time for a whole database. Redis

Tags: redis

I want to set a default expiration time for a whole database to not specify it for every key.

I'm using python and redis library (https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#)

So in my code insertion looks like this"

```
database.redis_restore_secret_codes.set(name=phone_number, 
value=secret_code, 
ex=config.EXPIRE_SECRET_CODE_MINUTES)
```

Database creation code:

```
import redis
redis_restore_secret_codes = redis.Redis(db=1, port=config.redis_port, host=config.redis_host)  # Individual logic
```

And setting every time `ex` parameter is tediously :)

Comment: You cannot do that with Redis.